# Save results from a loop

Tags: r, loops, output

i'm new to R. I have a question about how to save results in a loop to a file. Here is an example:

```
# Read in the data, set up variables
sdata<-read.csv("sdata.csv", header=T)
m=ncol(sdata)
x=matrix(0,m,4)
row.names(x) <- variable.names(sdata)
colnames(x) <- c( "Ground", "111d", "125d", "Ground")


for (i in 6:m){ 
Tukey1= HSD.test(lm(sdata[,i] ~ sdata$Medium+sdata$color+sdata$type+sdata$Micro), 'sdata$Micro')
x[i,] = Tukey1$goups[1:4,3]

}
```

I don't know how to do it with the loop for all data, so i just tried one of them,

```
Tukey1 = HSD.test(lm(sdata[,1] ~ sdata$Medium+sdata$color+sdata$type+sdata$Micro), 'sdata$Micro')
Tukey1
```

The results look like this:

```
$statistics
      Mean       CV   MSerror       HSD r.harmonic
  11.87421 3.102479 0.1357148 0.5288771   7.384615

$parameters
  Df ntr StudentizedRange
  24   4         3.901262

$means
       sdata_mg[, 6]       std  r      Min      Max
111d                  11.86369 0.5317421  6 11.08623 12.45651
125d                  11.74433 0.1663130  6 11.53504 12.02412
14d                   11.54073 0.3877921  8 10.80300 11.96797
Ground                12.16673 0.3391952 12 11.56278 12.86199

$comparison
NULL

$groups
     trt    means  M
1 Ground 12.16673  a
2 111d   11.86369 ab
3 125d   11.74433 ab
4 14d    11.54073  b
```

I want my output look like this:

```
0001 a ab ab b
0002 ...
0003 ...
...
```

How could i get such results in the loop?

I got an error：

```
   for (i in 6:m){ 
Tukey1=HSD.test(lm(sdata[,i] ~ sdata$Medium+sdata$color+sdata$type+sdata$Micro), 'sdata$Micro') 
x[i,] = Tukey1$groups[1:4,3]
} 

Error in row.names<-.data.frame(*tmp*, value = value) : missing values in 'row.names' are not allowed

Medium  color   type    Micro   replication JAT_0001    JAT_0002    JAT_UF_0003   .......
T13 Br  ST  14d 1   7.796561869 10.25722947 8.358342094
T13 Br  ST  111d    1   7.725102551 10.49954075 8.926736251
T13 Br  ST  125d    1   7.76897864  10.60934327 9.593081824
T13 Br  ST  125d    2   7.727733885 10.43269524 9.157324235
T13 Br  CO  14d 1   7.744205976 10.20154774 8.610439104
T13 Br  CO  111d    1   7.668092713 10.19312878 8.845051329
T13 Br  CO  125d    1   7.841236441 10.21631771 8.199416713
T13 Br  TL  Ground  1   7.437145528 10.6563327  8.957033378
T13 Br  TL  14d 1   7.609625475 10.49023043 8.896758964
T13 In  ST  Ground  1   7.595451012 10.80042474 9.464399064
T13 In  ST  Ground  2   7.730454076 10.64082958 8.542183261
T13 In  ST  111d    1   8.219528235 10.16869956 8.751080927
T13 In  TL  Ground  1   7.622781002 10.78092932 9.340316315
T2  Br  ST  14d 1   7.659787195 10.13839983 8.175650644
T2  Br  ST  14d 2   8.622211514 10.04158218 6.838194468
T2  Br  ST  14d 3   8.890290175 9.588902037 7.879420933
T2  Br  ST  Ground  1   7.961193023 10.16522895 8.81688728
T2  Br  CO  Ground  1   7.778931896 10.69110829 8.941482896
T2  Br  CO  Ground  2   8.038375873 10.57522016 8.982078909
T2  Br  CO  Ground  3   7.953854738 10.12257326 8.471493439
T2  Br  CO  111d    1   7.661298122 10.35416158 8.628662747
T2  Br  TL  Ground  1   7.766862289 10.92627748 9.9706205
T2  Br  TL  111d    1   7.899306069 9.796455434 7.92545749
T2  Br  TL  111d    2   8.062080142 9.812688772 8.186133545
T2  In  CO  Ground  1   7.717997141 10.0607044  8.413483731
T2  In  CO  14d 1   8.589243939 9.844666572 9.174649637
T2  In  CO  14d 2   8.207486485 10.78201791 9.450837609
```

Comment: The best way to start solving this will be with a reproducible example, e.g., a data set that we can use in order to run your code

Comment: Another suggestion would be to use the `data` argument in `lm()`

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you provide your data (upload it and provide a link in the question), or a representative sample that will all your code to run and reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your actual code?  If so, your `for()` statement is janked up.  Try

```
for (i in 1:m){ 
  Tukey1 = HSD.test(lm(sdata[,i] ~ sdata$Medium+sdata$color+sdata$type+sdata$Micro), 'sdata$Micro')
  x[i,] = Tukey1$goups[1:4,3]
}
```

You haven't described what errors you are getting but it seems like your issue is just extracting the part of the results you want, not running the regressions and tests.  If that is true, and if the above code doesn't fix your issue, please let us know what errors/warnings come up and provide `Tukey1` as data, rather than your raw data (I don't think the raw data helps).

Superficially it looks like aside from the issue I pointed out, your code is ok, so the bug you are experiencing is some small detail.  That's why people want reproduceable code rather than just a vague "it isn't working."

You might also change some of the wording in your question as nothing else in your question suggests you are having a hard time saving anything to a file.  It seems like you are just have a hard time copying results into a matrix.